# Rewriting via htaccess and pass data

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a multilingual website.
So I need to do something like this:

for example my site is: `example.com` and it has 2 foreign languages (en & de). Now i wanna install my site on `example.com/foreign` and if someone opens `example.com/en/*anything*` i want my website to open `example.com/foreign/*anything*` WITHOUT ANY REDIRECTION and also it should pass a parameter like LANG via POST or GET or anything else to detect the tables of database which are related to that language.

And the main problem is that `*anything*` can be anything like a directory name or something like `test.php?par1=value1&par2=value2`

so what's the solution for this?

Comment: What did you try first?

Comment: I tried:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \.\.\/\.\.\/foreign\/$1`

Comment: And where did that not do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.+)$ /foreign/$1?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I told that t`he url could be like this: `example.com/en/index.php?param1=value1`
so with your code the rewrite would be like this: `example.com/en/index.php?param1=value1?lang=en` which is not what we want

Comment: That is not correct, final URL will be: `example.com/en/index.php?param1=value1&lang=en`